# Using quad cpu server as workstation?

Tags: workstation

I have a quad socket server from my company we dont need anymore. I dont want to sell it so i wondered could i use it as a workstation. It has 4 amd opteron cpus 6274 (in 1 motherboard) a ssd disk with a ?raid controller i think?, 64 GB of RAM and 4x quiet noctua nh-u9do coolers. I dont need to good graphic card so pcie 2.0 wont be a big deal. I will be using the cpu with linux OS - for programming developing multitasking and stuff like that. Could i use this as a workstation or are most of the programs incapable of using its 64 cores and will run very slowly on only 1 thread?

Comment: Windows designed to put on a workstation would be unable to use more then 2 of the CPUs in that system.  This means Enterprise, Professional, and Home versions.  Only Windows Server can support a system with more then 2 physical CPUs.

Comment: I will be using linux and it does support 4 cpus.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.  I have 2 servers, a Dell t610 I think and another something or other, that I put Linux Mint on to use for company web-browsers/training stations.  They are not gaming machines by any standard but it servers the purpose(sorry worst pun ever).

Ramhound is correct above, to answer your question, yes you can, just don't expect awesomeness, I had to dig a little for drivers on the Mint install.

Comment: I dont need gaming. How does it perform in applications that are not designed for servers? Or even better in single threaded apps?

Comment: We have no problem running a Web browser and word processors.  If you're programming it may not like compiling and debuggers but we haven't run anything like that

Comment: I just checked your model and its a single cpu xeon pc. It should logically performe just fine. I am asking about 64 slower opteron cores.

Comment: For sure it's locked in another room, but I think that was the model, sorry it's not more help